# How strict is the block images feature in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Chrome's site settings provides options to always block / always allow / global default options.

When I choose always block and reload the page, I see that images don't load on the webpage, but I could still see the website favicon in the tab.

I used chrome's `Clear Browsing Data` to remove all `Cached images and files`, restarted the browser, cleared browsing data again, opened the webpage, and I still see the website favicon!

[image: Website Favicons]

There are 3 questions -

1. How strict is the block images feature in chrome?
   (**EDIT**: Are there any other types of images/situations that bypass block images feature?)
2. Why does the website favicon load even though images are blocked?
3. How do i stop chrome from loading favicons and other images (if any)?

Comment: Those icons are really hard to change. Even if you clear your cache it's hard to change. Try visiting `www.site.com/favicon.ico` directly in the address bar to reload the image, or in your case, clear it.

Comment: I don't think the icon is loading for existing pages. Open dev tools, F12, go to Network tab, and reload the page. Look for loading `favicon.ico`. You won't see it because it's in a special cache that's not easy to clear. If it does load for new pages, and you really want to stop it, you can set up a proxy, like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), to filter _all_ image requests and block them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't answer strictness of block images in chrome for sure. As @harrymc said, only the developers can truly answer that. I believe that it's going to be fairly strict, however, as images were the bane of surfers in the dial-up days, and it was a selling point, or convenience to enable that feature to speed page loads. Security may now trump convenience, but not then.

As for blocking favicon.ico gloablly, best option I know of is to install [AdBlock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/adblock%20plus) then add a custom rule for favicons.

Once installed, right-click on the Adblock Plus icon in toolbar, select "Options". On the options page, select the "Add Your Own Filters tab". In the top box (single line) type `favicon.ico` and click the "Add" button. Now you will still have to clear all the old ones out of cache, but none will be downloaded. Instead you get what looks like a document icon, a plain rectangle with a folded corner (in my case just a gray outline). A long list of them in the bookmark list does make it less convienent to find the page I want sometimes, however.

It is more complex, but you can create rules to deny, or allow, the favicon based on the domain it's from as well. You could also use custom rules to strictly block all images, just make a rule for each one. `*.(jp[e]?g|bmp|png|gif|tif+|flv)` or whatever you want.

## Update

To remove the icons from the cache, close Chrome, look for the directory `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/`, and delete two files: `Favicons` and `Favicons-journal`. Of course, unless you've installed something to stop them, Chrome will just reload them. Because they are cached 'en-mass' you can't pick and choose which ones to keep. However, if you have them blocked with AdBlock Plus, and find a site you want to have the icon for, just turn off AdBlock Plus for that site, reload, turn AdBlock Plus back on. Now it will be in the cache, but it will not be constantly refreshed, since downloading it will be blocked.

I realized that in the  section of a web page you can specify *anything* as the 'shortcut icon', and the browsers will mostly try to follow that. Therefore, I have had to change the filter for AddBlock Plus to have two entries, and as I find edge cases I may have to add other specialized version. I won't be updating this to include edge cases as I find them. (Probably not the idea for U&L or SE anyway.) I am giving the two new lines as they are now, as examples of how to make it work. I use:

```
favicon.*
*.ico
```

The second one is possibly too generic, for example it will prevent me from downloading icons that are .ico files from a site for customizing my screen. It won't even let me see them to try. But, because I'll know when I want to do that, and it's easy to turn AdBlock Plus on and off, I can avoid that problem while catching most of the shortcut icons that are loaded by Chrome without my control.

Comment: Solved: After clearing cache, and deleted `Favicons` and `Favicons-journal`, i set `*/favicon.ico` in µblock My Filters = No more favicons

Answer (score 3):

As far as goes my understanding, block images pertains to the display of the
HTML page. It blocks the fetching of images and therefore speeds-up the display
of the page (not to mention that some images are used as trackers).
This option should not block the usage of images elsewhere in the Chrome
user-interface, including favicons.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Use_of_favicon), in addition to Tabs, favicons are also used in the
Links bar and for Bookmarks,

Firefox has an in-built feature option to disable display of favicons on tabs,
but there is no such option in Google Chrome.

However, you can still implement this using the
[No Favicons Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-favicons/mnaaoncljflaeohddihlkbfooicoajej), described as :

> Some of us do not like favicons (site icons).
>
> Chrome does not have an option to block favicons like Firefox does. 
>   This extension does its best to rid the Chrome UI of the clutter of
>   favicons.  It will replace the favicon of all sites with a choice of
>   clean icons or let you specify a your own icon.

Restart Chrome after installing the extension.
I do not know whether this extension will turn off favicons from every place where
they are used in Chrome (Tabs, Links bar and Bookmarks) - you have to try and see.

Reference : [Hide & remove Favicons in Chrome & Firefox tabs](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/disable-remove-favicons-in-chrome-firefox/).

Comment: That's the best solution I have found. If you feel that strongly about favicons, Firefox is a great browser.

Comment: For the principal question: Only the Chrome developers can fully answer it. AFAIK, block images is meant for HTML only - it does not apply to anything which is not part of the document or is not displayed inside its tab.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0):

In an odd sense, a favicon isn't *really* part of the site - while you can set a per page favicon with markup, the convention also lets you put them on webroot. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)'s article goes into that, and per browser handling a *little* more in depth

So *strictly* speaking, a favicon is 'special' and no other images should load if you set your browser not to.

[chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402) *also* has a bug related to this which indicates that it requests favicons *every request* if there isn't one.

So

1. No. This is slightly unusual behaviour
2. Cause your browser is a *little* odd, and in any case, it may be pulling the favicon from *outside* the webpage.
3. Other images should be blocked anyway